# How to make uisegment control label horizontal

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

In my application I am trying to make a vertical `UISegmentControl`. It's working fine in vertical mode but the labels are also vertical. How can I make the `UISegmentControl` labels horizontal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to browse the segment subview to find labels and make rotation on the label :

```
for(UIView *v in segmentedView.subviews)
{
  if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
  {
    double angle = 45.0;
    v.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * angle / 180.0); // rotate to 45 degree
  }
}
```